# What is the logic behind subnet mask value?

Tags: networking, subnet

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the essentials of a Subnet mask?](https://superuser.com/questions/186850/what-are-the-essentials-of-a-subnet-mask)

hi,

In all the machines having internet connections , i can see a value called subnet mask associated with the TCP/IP properties of the ethernet interface.

what is the logic behind it? or how can i calculate from a particular IP address?

I just read it from some blogs but it was not clear

Comment: And -1 [for ignoring this](http://img.skitch.com/20100924-cmr145qd78m2ca3rp3af1wupj6.png). (Hence, see also [
What is a subnet mask, and the difference between a subnet mask of 255.255.255.0 and 255.0.0.0?](http://superuser.com/questions/54802/what-is-a-subnet-mask-and-the-difference-between-a-subnet-mask-of-255-255-255-0))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is best answered by Wikipedia, see [CIDR notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) to understand the importance of subnet masks.

Answer (score 1):

The subnet mask is what determines how many clients are assigned ip addresses within that domain and how many subnets can be created.  That is determined by the subnet mask.  A 255.255.255.0 can have 254 hosts (clients with IP addresses) on a single subnet.  With two subnets there are 126 hosts.  While a subnet address with 255.0.0.0 with a single subnet can yield over 16 million hosts.

There is a simple calculator [here](http://www.subnet-calculator.com/subnet.php?net_class=C) that is useful.

Since this is only a simplified answer this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subnetwork) goes into greater detail.